# How to do data migration data from Liferay 6 to Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, upgrade, liferay-7

Currently, I use Liferay 6, my data is stored in DDL and the data store format is XML. While, the data format in Liferay 7 is JSON. How can I do this upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

When your data is persisted in your DB, Liferays DXP (7.0) upgrade-client program ([DXP Upgrade](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-0/running-the-upgrade-process)) should transform your data or taking care that persisted data is still usable with DXP.
You can find some more information about portal upgrade on the [Developer Network: UPGRADING TO LIFERAY PORTAL](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-0/upgrading-to-liferay-7). Please also note the Upgrade-Preparing steps.